# Startup.cs is not getting updated appsettings.json value asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, startup, appsettings

I am getting some of the custom values from `appsettings.json` on `Startup.cs`. As per the requirement, a user can update values of `appsettings.json`. It is working fine for the first time already added value but whenever I update any value, It is taking old one only.
How do I get updated value here? My sample code is as below.
**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      string key = Configuration["PRD:key"];
}
```

Comment: ConfigureServices only runs once :) You should probably inject `IOptionsMonitor<YourOptionsType>` to a class and get the fresh values there.

Comment: @juunas do you have any example?

Comment: Here is an example of `IOptionsSnapshot`, which is similar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reload-configuration-data-with-ioptionssnapshot

Comment: How did you modify value in `appsettings.json`? Where will you use `string key = Configuration["PRD:key"];`? For this code, it will run one time, and you will not be able to access this line if you did not restart your application. Then, how and where will you access the updated value?

Comment: After publishing the website, I can see `appseetings.json`. I am updating the values there. I am using the value on `Startup.cs` only.